# "HOW DOOM FIRE WAS DONE" - Re-implementation of a fire animation that results in a noise animation

Tags: java, animation

(nota: a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example is provided at the end of this question)

## Summary

1. Context, Aim & Problem
2. My (possibly wrong?) understanding of the author's explanations and sources *- note: I have to explain it to you, since my errors can come from a bad understanding of what to do or a bad implementation of my behalf...*
3. What I have done
4. Expected results, Actual results & Question
5. Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

## Context, Aim & Problem

I study the animation of the famous DOOM game according to http://fabiensanglard.net/doom_fire_psx/, which consists in generating fire.

A full version of the author's code is: https://github.com/fabiensanglard/DoomFirePSX/blob/master/flames.html

I ended with this implementation but the result I have is an animation of noise (that's the problem). Indeed, at the end of this animation, I get this result:

[image]

---

## My (possibly wrong?) understanding of the author's explanations and sources

### First approach: implementation of the main principles, and simplification of the fire (because replaced by a simple gradient of colors)

1. Set up a precisely filled color set: this set defines a gradient that looks like fire. There are 36 colours from white to black, and among them there are yellow, orange and red. This set does not contain any duplicates.
2. Iterate a first time on the canvas pixels. Here the goal is to color all pixels black (i.e.: the last color of the set).
3. Iterate a second time on the canvas. This time, we must color in white the pixels of the first line at the bottom (i.e.: the first color of the set).
4. Iterate again on the canvas, but only from the second bottom line (included), not from the first bottom line (which is thus excluded). For each iterated pixel, we modify its color in this way: we take the color of its direct lower pixel, we find the index of this color in all the colors, we add 1 to this index: we obtain another index called i2, we find the color whose index is i2, then we apply this color to this iterated pixel.

Once the execution is finished, there will be several gradients, each containing 36 lines (36 colors).

### To make it really look like fire.

The program explained by http://fabiensanglard.net/doom_fire_psx/ goes further than that, of course: it uses the pseudo-random twice, to get something that doesn't look like a simple gradient but does look like fire.

The idea is as follows. For the pixel being iterated:

We get the color index of the pixel located just below. Then, we get the color, in the color set, whose index is this index + a random number involving a slight shift (by a maximum of 2 squares if I remember correctly). Thus, we can model the acceleration of the variation in the temperature of the particles.

And, in addition, we consider the pixel located a little to the left of the pixel being iterated. "A little bit" = according to the same random number of chip number 1. It is this pixel located a little to the left that will be assigned the color recovered in chip N°1. Thus, we can model the horizontal displacement to the left of the flames.

So we see that it is a triangle work (because we take the pixel being iterated, the one just below and the one a little to the left).

#### Pseudo-random used to model the acceleration of particle temperature variation acceleration

A random number is generated, between 0 and 3 both included and is used here:

`firePixels[src - FIRE_WIDTH ] = pixel - (rand & 1);`

A slight variation in the colour to be applied is therefore introduced.

#### Pseudo-random used to model the horizontal displacement to the left of the flames.

In addition to what we have just seen, pseudo-random used on the pixels, per line is also used.

This same random number is re-used here:

`var dst = src - rand + 1;
firePixels[dst - FIRE_WIDTH ] = pixel - (rand & 1);`

Here, a slight shift is made horizontally.

---

## What I have done

All the explanations above have been implemented, but my program outputs bad results. So:

1. Either I didn't understand well the thinking,
2. Or I badly implemented it.

You will find the implementation's sources below.

## Expected results, Actual results & Question

I expect to have several vertical gradients (each from bottom to top). "Several" because my canvas' height is greater than the number of the colors of my gradients and because I use a modulo to choose the color to apply. These gradients must be like those of the curse (http://fabiensanglard.net/doom_fire_psx/).

The actual results are: I get several noises instead.

My question is: why doesn't it work? I think I well understood what to do. Perhaps I forgot ssomething in the implementation, but what?

My question is: why doesn't it work? I think I well understood what to do. Perhaps I forgot ssomething in the implementation, but what?

## Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

### Launcher.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int width = 800, height = 800;
        Gui gui = new Gui(width, height);
        gui.setUp("DOOM-like fire");
        gui.setVisible(true);

        Colors colors = new FireColors(new ArrayList<>());
        gui.colorize(colors.getLastColor(), -1, -1);  // Setting black anywhere
        gui.colorize(colors.getColorAtIndex(0), -1, height - 1);  // Setting white, in a lower line

        new ThreadPainter(0, colors, gui, width, height).schedulePainting();
    }

}
```

### Gui.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

class Gui extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;
    private BufferedImage buffered_image;

    Gui(int width, int height) {
        buffered_image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        panel = new JPanel() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
                super.paintComponent(graphics);
                graphics.drawImage(buffered_image, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };
    }

    void setUp(String title) {
        setTitle(title);
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(buffered_image.getWidth(), buffered_image.getHeight());
        setContentPane(panel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    void colorize(Color color, int x_parameter, int y_parameter) {
        for(int y = (y_parameter == -1 ? 0 : y_parameter); y <= (y_parameter == -1 ? this.getHeight() - 1 : y_parameter); y++) {
            for(int x = (x_parameter == -1 ? 0 : x_parameter); x <= (x_parameter== -1 ? this.getWidth() - 1 : x_parameter); x++) {
                buffered_image.setRGB(x, y, color.getRGB());
            }
        }
        panel.repaint();
    }

    int getRGBAtCoordinates(int x, int y) {
        return buffered_image.getRGB(x, y);
    }

}
```

### ThreadPainter.java

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

class ThreadPainter extends Timer {
    private Gui gui;
    private Colors colors;
    private int delay;
    private int height;
    private int width;

    ThreadPainter(int delay, Colors colors, Gui gui, int width, int height) {
        this.colors = colors;
        this.gui = gui;
        this.delay = delay;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    void schedulePainting() {
        this.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int number_of_colored_portions = height / colors.getSize();
                    // int locking_changement_of_color = 0;
                    for(int y = height - 2; y >= 0; y--) {

                        //if(locking_changement_of_color == number_of_colored_portions) {
                            //locking_changement_of_color = 0;
                        /*} else {
                            index_of_color_to_apply = index_of_found_color;
                        }*/

                        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                            int rand = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 3.0) & 3;
                            int below_pixel_rgb = gui.getRGBAtCoordinates(x, y + 1);
                            int index_of_found_color = colors.getIndexOfColor(below_pixel_rgb);
                            int index_of_color_to_apply = (index_of_found_color + (rand & 1)) % colors.getSize();

                            int x_copy = x - rand + 1;
                            if(x_copy <= 0) {
                                x_copy = 0;
                            } else if(x_copy >= width) {
                                x_copy = width - 1;
                            }
                            gui.colorize(colors.getColorAtIndex(index_of_color_to_apply), x_copy, y);
                        }

                        //locking_changement_of_color++;
                        //Thread.sleep(10);
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, this.delay);
    }

}
```

### Colors.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.List;

abstract class Colors {
    List<Color> colors;

    Color getColorAtIndex(int index) {
        return colors.get(index);
    }

    int getIndexOfColor(int rgb) throws Exception {
        for (int x = 0; x < colors.size(); x++) {
            if(colors.get(x).getRGB() == rgb) {
                return x;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Color not found in the list!");
    }

    int getSize() {
        return colors.size();
    }

    Color getLastColor() {
        return colors.get(colors.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

### FireColors.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.List;

class FireColors extends Colors {

    FireColors(List<Color> colors) {

        this.colors = colors;

        this.colors.add(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        this.colors.add(new Color(239, 239, 199));
        this.colors.add(new Color(223, 223, 159));
        this.colors.add(new Color(207, 207, 111));
        this.colors.add(new Color(183, 183, 55));
        this.colors.add(new Color(183, 183, 47));
        this.colors.add(new Color(183, 175, 47));
        this.colors.add(new Color(191, 175, 47));
        this.colors.add(new Color(191, 167, 39));
        this.colors.add(new Color(191, 167, 39));
        this.colors.add(new Color(191, 159, 31));
        this.colors.add(new Color(191, 159, 31));
        this.colors.add(new Color(199, 151, 31));
        this.colors.add(new Color(199, 143, 23));
        this.colors.add(new Color(199, 135, 23));
        this.colors.add(new Color(207, 135, 23));
        this.colors.add(new Color(207, 127, 15));
        this.colors.add(new Color(207, 119, 15));
        this.colors.add(new Color(207, 111, 15));
        this.colors.add(new Color(215, 103, 15));
        this.colors.add(new Color(215, 95, 7));
        this.colors.add(new Color(223, 87, 7));
        this.colors.add(new Color(223, 87, 7));
        this.colors.add(new Color(223, 79, 7));
        this.colors.add(new Color(199, 71, 7));
        this.colors.add(new Color(191, 71, 7));
        this.colors.add(new Color(175, 63, 7));
        this.colors.add(new Color(159, 47, 7));
        this.colors.add(new Color(143, 39, 7));
        this.colors.add(new Color(119, 31, 7));
        this.colors.add(new Color(103, 31, 7));
        this.colors.add(new Color(87, 23, 7));
        this.colors.add(new Color(71, 15, 7));
        this.colors.add(new Color(47, 15, 7));
        this.colors.add(new Color(7, 7, 7));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many small problems, so here is fixed version with comments for you to understand (I've combined classes into one file to simplify):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Launcher {
    private static class Gui extends JFrame {
        final int width;
        final int height;
        final JPanel panel;
        final BufferedImage buffered_image;

        Gui(final String title, final int width, final int height) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.buffered_image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            this.panel = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public void paintComponent(final Graphics graphics) {
                    super.paintComponent(graphics);
                    graphics.drawImage(Gui.this.buffered_image, 0, 0, null);
                }
            };
            this.setTitle(title);
            this.setContentPane(this.panel);
            this.setSize(width, height);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setVisible(true);
        }

        void colorize(final Color color, final int x, final int y) {
            if ((x < 0) || (x >= this.width) || (y < 0) || (y >= this.height))
                return;
            this.buffered_image.setRGB(x, y, color.getRGB());
        }

        int getRGBAtCoordinates(final int x, final int y) {
            return this.buffered_image.getRGB(x, y);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        final List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<>();
        colors.add(new Color(0, 0, 0)); // black
        colors.add(new Color(7, 7, 7));
        colors.add(new Color(47, 15, 7));
        colors.add(new Color(71, 15, 7));
        colors.add(new Color(87, 23, 7));
        colors.add(new Color(103, 31, 7));
        colors.add(new Color(119, 31, 7));
        colors.add(new Color(143, 39, 7));
        colors.add(new Color(159, 47, 7));
        colors.add(new Color(175, 63, 7));
        colors.add(new Color(191, 71, 7));
        colors.add(new Color(199, 71, 7));
        colors.add(new Color(223, 79, 7));
        colors.add(new Color(223, 87, 7));
        colors.add(new Color(223, 87, 7));
        colors.add(new Color(215, 95, 7));
        colors.add(new Color(215, 103, 15));
        colors.add(new Color(207, 111, 15));
        colors.add(new Color(207, 119, 15));
        colors.add(new Color(207, 127, 15));
        colors.add(new Color(207, 135, 23));
        colors.add(new Color(199, 135, 23));
        colors.add(new Color(199, 143, 23));
        colors.add(new Color(199, 151, 31));
        colors.add(new Color(191, 159, 31));
        colors.add(new Color(191, 159, 31));
        colors.add(new Color(191, 167, 39));
        colors.add(new Color(191, 167, 39));
        colors.add(new Color(191, 175, 47));
        colors.add(new Color(183, 175, 47));
        colors.add(new Color(183, 183, 47));
        colors.add(new Color(183, 183, 55));
        colors.add(new Color(207, 207, 111));
        colors.add(new Color(223, 223, 159));
        colors.add(new Color(239, 239, 199));
        colors.add(new Color(255, 255, 255)); // white

        final Gui gui = new Gui("DOOM-like fire", 800, 800);

        final Color black = colors.get(0);
        final Color white = colors.get(colors.size() - 1);
        final Dimension dim = gui.getContentPane().getSize(); // get actual size, without title/borders
        for (int y = 0; y < dim.height; y++) {
            final Color clr = y < (dim.height - 1) ? black : white;
            for (int x = 0; x < dim.width; x++)
                gui.colorize(clr, x, y);
        }

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            final Random rnd = new Random();

            Color getColorAtIndex(final int index) {
                if (index < 0)
                    return colors.get(0); // minimal color is black
                return colors.get(index);
            }

            int getIndexOfColor(final int rgb) {
                for (int x = 0; x < colors.size(); x++)
                    if (colors.get(x).getRGB() == rgb)
                        return x;
                throw new RuntimeException("Color not found in the list!");
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int x = 0; x < dim.width; x++) {
                    for (int y = 1; y < dim.height; y++) {
                        final int new_index = this.getIndexOfColor(gui.getRGBAtCoordinates(x, y)) - this.rnd.nextInt(2);
                        final int new_x = (x - this.rnd.nextInt(3)) + 1;
                        gui.colorize(this.getColorAtIndex(new_index), new_x, y - 1);
                    }
                }
                gui.repaint();
            }
        }, 0, 40); // start immediately and repeat every 40ms
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, I converted what I needed to run it in Processing and looks great.

Comment: Your variable `new_index` contains the index of the color of the pixel you are iterating on. However, the author of the curse says that you should take the index of the color of the pixel located just below the pixel you are iterating on. That's what I did with `index_of_color_to_apply` in my own code. Btw, what happens if `new_x` is out of the bounds of your canvas? Globally you did the same as I did. What great modifications did you do please?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler I'm getting index of pixel at `y`, but setting `y-1`, thus I'm using pixel below to set pixel above it

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler `if ((x < 0) || (x >= this.width) || (y < 0) || (y >= this.height))` is the anwser to pixel out of bounds

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler check the comments - they are main differences

Comment: Indeed, in fact the pb was due to 1) my modulo 2) the lack of period set for the thread 3) the wrong width/height that must be retrieved from the canvas.